# error in composer upgrade

Tags: magento2

I got one lamalls dependency plugin error when i try to composer upgrade .

[image]

Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you need to update your composer itself (with a composer self-update). That should solve your problem.
Best regards
JG Cabanas

Comment: As I was 1st to answer,  kudo and like would be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with Composer, By installing latest version of Composer solved it. [The bug](https://github.com/composer/composer/commit/b1bfb9bb65641d35434209c2c60169a92e99d1e3) for the constant variable `PRE_COMMAND_RUN` is raised and closed.

Thanks ...